# Modifying existing PCB design of nodeMCU

Tags: pcb-design, nodemcu

I am looking for a way to modify existing nodeMCU PCB layout. I want to re-build it from scratch and add more components to it namely 0.96dpi LED display and few buttons. I want to also change the existing dimensions of the PCB Board. That means I need a project file, whoes components placement can be modified. I am using Eagle for PCB designing.

P.S I can't use genral purpose PCB for a fully fledged working Prototype.

Comment: Nodemcu is open source, have you checked its [repo](https://github.com/nodemcu) ?

Comment: Yes, but they contain .lbr file and greber files. I am unable to modify the internal layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may edit the lbr library part

```
ESP12E_DEVKIT.lbr
```

found here [Github](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit-v1.0) .

The tutorial video is here [YouTube](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yY9WUC0oiK0&t=21s)

Here is another tutorial for [Library layout update](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fgG7AYtI5rI)

See if it helps.

Comment: I am unable to edit .lbr, apart from that none of the videos are helpful.

Comment: @M.S.P what kind of issue/error are you facing while trying to edit that lbr ? Is it similar to what has been discussed [here](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/19385/l/lbr-files-locked?displayFullThread=true)?

Answer (score 0):

The design files are made in Altium Designer. You'll have to open those in that, or you'll have to somehow convert the files to something Eagle would open.

It may be possible, but from a quick google, this seems to be a **long** and **painful** process.

---

However, looking at how simple the NodeMCU board is, it shouldn't take you long to "just" replicate it from [the schematic](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit-v1.0/blob/master/NODEMCU_DEVKIT_V1.0.PDF)!